# Opening Protected Workbook on Multiple Computers with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I currently have a program that is opening and using a protected workbook called Nutrition Information to retrieve nutritional data.

```
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(fileName:= _
    ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Nutritional Information.xlsm", Password:=4321)
```

My program works perfectly as long as only one person is using it at a time. I was looking into the possibility of having multiple copies of the document (One for each dining location at my job) which all look to the Nutritional Information workbook for the data that they need.

I have tried a few things to make this possible. The first thing I tried was using the "Get Data" option to have a master Nutritional Information document and then local documents that are dynamic copies of the master file but this didn't seem to work because Get Data doesn't seem to work with protected files.

I then tested to see if the document would work even if both programs were referencing the Nutritional Information file at the same time. I was able to get the copy of the document which opened Nutritional Information to work but the second copy had something interesting happen. On the second copy I was prompted to put in the password for the Nutritional Information document (even though the password is given in the call to open the document) and once I put in the password the second copy worked perfectly fine. The two even worked at the same time as long as one of them had the password put in manually.

Is there a way to prevent this manual insertion of the password on the second copy of the document? Or are there any other ways that I could have this sort of functionality?

Comment: Did you try to write a function to test to see if the workbook is open first then if it is set the open string to open as a copy, which will change the name of the file that is being opened to "Copy of...." and if the file isnt opened then run the code to open that workbook as you already have it?

Comment: One option if there is data that needs to be moved from one Workbook to another is either `VLOOKUP` or you can treat the master Nutritional Value workbook as a database and then the other workbooks will update without having to open the master workbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In regards to my comment above:  I got this function on SO (I dont remember the post it was on to give proper credit to the person who wrote it unfortunately).

```
Function IsWorkBookOpen(FileName As String)
    Dim ff As Long, ErrNo As Long

    On Error Resume Next
    ff = FreeFile()
    Open FileName For Input Lock Read As #ff
    Close ff
    ErrNo = Err
    On Error GoTo 0

    Select Case ErrNo
    Case 0:    IsWorkBookOpen = False
    Case 70:   IsWorkBookOpen = True
    Case Else: Error ErrNo
    End Select
End Function
```

Then you can use:

```
ret= IsWorkbookOpen(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Nutritional Information.xlsm")
If ret = False then
    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(fileName:= _
    ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Nutritional Information.xlsm", Password:=4321)
Else
    ....enter code here to open the workbook as read only with the password.
```

Comment: I believe I could just get away with always opening a copy of the file rather than the original. This would also solve the similar issue of if someone is editing the Nutritional Information file. I looked around for how to open a copy of a file but I'm not quite finding anything. Can you please explain what you mean by "Set the open string to open as a copy"?

Comment: my pleasure.  Glad i could help.